# Can you base a trigger on whether you're in a drag event?

Tags: wpf, triggers, drag-and-drop, datatemplate

I want to style a `Border` via a `Trigger` in response to being dragged over vs simple mouse-over.

More specifically, we have a list of items that displays a hardware port (such as Port 1, Port 2, etc.) then next to it, the device that's connected to that port.  For normal mouse-over events, we want to highlight the devices.  However, if we're in a drag-drop operation, we want to highlight the port.

For instance here's some faux MultiTriggers describing what I want to do.  It uses a faux property called `IsDragInProgress` which I made up for this example.  That's what I'm trying to achieve.

```
<DataTemplate x:Key="TestTemplate">

    <DockPanel>

        <Border x:Name="PortHighlight" DockPanel.Dock="Left">
            <TextBlock>
                <Run Text="{Binding PortName}" />
                <Run Text=": " />
            </TextBlock>
        </Border>

        <Border x:Name="DeviceHighlight">
            <TextBlock Text="{Binding DeviceName}" />
        </Border>

    </DockPanel>

    <DataTemplate.Triggers>

        <MultiTrigger>

            <MultiTrigger.Conditions>
                <Condition Property="IsMouseOver" Value="True" />
                <Condition Property="IsDragInProgress" Value="False" />
            </MultiTrigger.Conditions>

            <Setter TargetName="DeviceHighlight" Property="Background" Value="Yellow" />

        </MultiTrigger>

        <MultiTrigger>

            <MultiTrigger.Conditions>
                <Condition Property="IsMouseOver" Value="True" />
                <Condition Property="IsDragInProgress" Value="True" />
            </MultiTrigger.Conditions>

            <Setter TargetName="PortHighlight" Property="Background" Value="Yellow" />

        </MultiTrigger>

    </DataTemplate.Triggers>

</DataTemplate>
```

So can this be done?  Is there any existing property I can poll in place of the faux `IsDragInProgress`?

Comment: I don't believe OnEnter has anything to do with if you're dragging or not as it fired either way.  Plus, that's an event, not a property, correct?  Again, I'm looking for something I can test if I'm dragging or not.

Answer (score 0):

You could use a [DataTrigger](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.datatrigger.aspx).  You would create the IsDragInProgress property in your viewmodel.  Then you would have to turn that property on/off when a drag starts and ends.

Edit:

```
<Grid x:Name="LayoutRoot">
    <Border x:Name="border" AllowDrop="True" Drop="border_Drop" DragEnter="border_DragEnter" DragLeave="border_DragLeave" Background="White"></Border>
    <Ellipse Height="50" Width="50" Fill="Green" MouseMove="Ellipse_MouseMove" />
</Grid>
```

In codebehind:

```
private void Ellipse_MouseMove(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
    {
        Ellipse ellipse = sender as Ellipse;
        if (ellipse != null && e.LeftButton == MouseButtonState.Pressed)
        {
            DragDrop.DoDragDrop(ellipse,
                                 ellipse.Fill.ToString(),
                                 DragDropEffects.Copy);
        }
    }

    private void border_DragEnter(object sender, DragEventArgs e)
    {
        border.Background = new SolidColorBrush(Colors.Blue);
    }

    private void border_DragLeave(object sender, DragEventArgs e)
    {
        border.Background = new SolidColorBrush(Colors.White);
    }

    private void border_Drop(object sender, DragEventArgs e)
    {
        border.Background = new SolidColorBrush(Colors.White);
    }
```

In my brief testing, this seemed pretty reliable.  Instead of changing the Background color, change the property on your viewmodel (which in turn fires the DataTrigger).

Good Luck!

Comment: The problem with that approach is every single thing responsible for initiating a drag would have to set that, and everything that terminates a drag would have to clear that.  Plus, how do you handle cases where you start a drag, but then cancel the drag before completing it?  I'm really surprised there's no way to just ask the framework 'Hey... is someone dragging something now?'

Comment: That could be an issue... But I quickly tried a wpf app based on the code [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms742859.aspx).  I changed the color of my drop target (a Border) area to blue in DragEnter, then change it back to white in DragLeave and Drop events.  When handling those events, I couldn't fool it into remaining blue... I can't say it is foolproof though... Hope you find a solution.

Comment: What if you don't leave, or drop? I.e. you cancel the drag by pressing Esc?  Actually, any chance you could post the code you're referring to (or update the above with it?)